# You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0'' at line 1

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem I'm testing my table in mysql everything was working then I delete it the data now when I tried my php script running it  gives me this error
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '0'' at line 1
I checked my code everything seems right. Can anyone help me. Thank you

```
UPDATE NewsLetter 
SET Active='1' 
WHERE Email='".$email."' AND Hash='".$hash."' AND Active='0'
```

Comment: UPDATE NewsLetter SET Active='1' WHERE Email='".$email."' AND Hash='".$hash."' AND Active='0'

Comment: What does the query look like with the variables actually substituted into it?

Comment: The error message you posted refers to `'0''` - Are you sure you aren't appending another single quote on the end somewhere?

Comment: post the php code that sets the query variable

Comment: what are the values of $email and $hash?

Answer (score 1):

I will actually save you the trouble of responding to the comments.

Simply put, don't do this! You don't appear to be sanitizing your input variables, and this method of string concatenation leads me to believe you're using the builtin mysql_* functions. Don't!

Try using PDO! Your query becomes:

```
$statement_handle = $database->prepare("UPDATE NewsLetter SET Active=1 WHERE Email = ? AND Hash = ?"); 

$statement_handle->execute(array($email, $hash));
```

Bind variables!

Comment: I'm all for showing someone a better way to do something but at least wait until you can provide them with a solution to their original situation as well.